# Смена картинки на другой странице по клику js

Tags: javascript

есть код, который меняет src изображения по клику на div, проблема в том, что изображение должно меняться на другой странице, то есть естественно код не работает. Помогите поправить, в js еще зеленый.

```js
$('.fItem img').on('click',  function (e) {
  var srcS = $(this).attr('src');
  $('.product__img img').attr('src', srcS);
});
```

Comment: На какой другой странице? На другой(ом) вкладке (окне браузера)?

Comment: переход по ссылке категории ведет на страницу соответствующей записи, картинка в запись должна подставиться из категории

Comment: то есть открывается новая вкладка, да

Comment: Js работает лишь в пределах страницы. Можно обернуть вашу картинку в ссылку, в ссылку подставить id нужного поста. Или почитайте как сгенерировать и перейти по ссылке с помощью js

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы на другой странице что-то сработало, туда надо передать информацию. Сделать это можно, например, с помощью добавления в адрес ссылки хеша c путём до картинки:

```
<a href="http://mysite.ru/another-page.html#path_to_pic.jpg">Переход на другую страницу</a>
```

А на той странице, куда осуществлён переход, обрабатываете адрес, вытаскиваете из него путь к картинке и подставляете в `src`:

```
let link = window.location.href.split('#').pop(); //получаем то, что после #
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].setAttribute('src', link); //подставляем в src
```